# Why doesn't PIL/Pillow crop work?

Tags: python, image, crop, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use Pillow to crop an image, but it doesn't seem to work. I've got the following code:

```
im = Image.open('the_image.jpg')
print 'ORIGINAL SIZE: ', im.size
im.crop((1087, 0, 1820, 2197))
print 'CROPPED SIZE: ', im.size
```

which prints this in the terminal:

```
ORIGINAL SIZE:  (2908, 2197)
CROPPED SIZE:  (2908, 2197)
```

Does anybody know why the cropping doesn't seem to work? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because of that `im.crop((1087, 0, 1820, 2197))` doesn't crop your image in-place but it returns the cropped image.

You can do :

```
im = Image.open('the_image.jpg')
print 'ORIGINAL SIZE: ', im.size
cr=im.crop((1087, 0, 1820, 2197))
print 'CROPPED SIZE: ', cr.size
```

Comment: That is pretty weird, because `im.thumbnail()` does resize in place. Well, it works now.. :-)  Thanks a million!

Comment: I couldn't yet. You can only accept answers if the question is at least I think 10 minutes old. But I now accepted it.. :-)

Comment: @kramer65 yeah i missed that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do

```
im.crop((1087, 0, 1820, 2197)).save('the_image.jpg','jpeg')
```